# How to get an existing Doc key in Firestore JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firebase FireStrore. I added the Doc with add() method, so the id of a new Doc is random string. Now I want to update this doc. For this purpose in keys when I know the Doc id I do the next:

```
let someRef = db.collection('users').doc('knownID')
let updateEmail = someRef.update({email: 'newemail@gmail.com'})
```

But I don't know the Doc id. So, how to get this ID to update the Doc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the ID of a document in order to create a reference to it.  If you don't know an ID, all you can do is make a query to find it, which means that you know something about its contents.  Other than knowing the ID or performing a query, there is no way to read or write a document.

If you create a document with `add()`, you may want to considering remembering the generated ID somewhere else to use later.

Comment: In general - it looks like I have to use something unique for ids of my docs, email for example. But if I will use emails like IDs, then if my user use change email functionality then I have to copy all user data to a new Doc to create this new Doc with changed email. It's so inconvenient.